# Fourier-Jacobi expansion for Siegel modular forms of non parallel weight

Tags: modular-forms

For Siegel modular forms of parallel weight there is a good theory of Fourier-Jacobi expansions (as for example in Faltings-Chai) and I suspect that there is a similar theory for the general case, but I am not able to find a good reference.

So my question is: do we have a Fourier-Jacobi expansion theory for Siegel modular forms of not necessarily parallel weight? If this is true, where can I find a good explanation?

This question is related to my other question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199621/a-question-about-the-paper-the-main-conjecture-for-gl2-by-skinner-and-urba), indeed in the parallel weight case the answer to the other question is yes (because of the projection formula) and I think that a good way to prove it in general is to use Fourier-Jacobi expansion (as Skinner and Urban apparently do, without giving a reference).